# How to call jenkins shared library method in jenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

### Description

I am converting my project jenkinsfiles to shared library, create re-usable methods in groovy. I am using extended_choice_parameter plugin for parameterized build in Jenkins. I use this to pass values like cluster, stage, credentials etc to jenkins job.
Now i want to use Jenkins shared library where i can define functions with parameters and call them in jenkinsfile with arguments.

### Problem

While using shared library for parameters which is a block inside "pipeline" in jenkinsFile, i am getting error related to usage of parameter function. I have created this file **jobParams.groovy**

```
List commonParams() {
     //return list of parameters
     def paramsList = [
        choice(name: 'stage', choices: ['lab', 'dev', 'qa', 'uat', 'prod'], description: 'select stage name' ),
        choice(name: 'playbook',
                choices: [  '',
                            'Linux',
                            'Unix',
                            'CentOS',
                            'Ubuntu',
                            'Debian'
                          ],
                description: 'select the playbook to deploy'
              ),
        credentials(name: 'sshCredentialsId', defaultValue: 'lc_ikep_ansible', credentialType: "Username with password", required: true, description: 'SSH credentials for Ansible' ) ,
        string(name: 'ansibleTags', defaultValue: '', description: 'Type in ansibleTags separated by space, example: "pre-install ikep-acls"'),
        string(name: 'extraVars', defaultValue: '', description: 'Type in extraVars in format: --extra-vars=\'{key1: {key2: \"value2\", key3: \"value3\"}}\''),
        choice(name: 'verboseLogging', choices: ['', '-v', '-vvv', '-vvvv'], description: 'Select ansible verbose logging'),
        booleanParam( name: 'forceDeploy',
                      defaultValue: false,
                      description: 'Activate to force deployment for non-master branches'
                    )
     ]

     return paramsList

}
```

Now i am calling this List in jenkinsfile as these parameters are generated before we click BUILD in jenkins.
Using following code, i am able to print all the parameters defined in LIST above. But now how can i use this as parameter to generate build parameters in Jenkins.

```
/* Pipeline */
def commonParams = jobParams.commonParams()
    String listAsString =  "[\"${commonParams.join('", "')}\"]"
    echo "printing variables ${listAsString}"
```

Please suggest as i did not find a valid usecase while searching internet. Inside **pipeline block in jenkins file** I tried following but it gives error stating

```
pipeline {
  agent { label "ansibleDeployments"}
  options { 
    ansiColor('xterm') 
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
  environment {
    ansibleTags = 'all'
    }
  parameters {
    (listAsString)
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
WorkflowScript: 67: Expected a build parameter definition @ line 67, column 5.
       (listAsString)
       ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you're passing the string instead of the list, the parameters block might receive a list.

```
parameters << commonParams
```

Also you can check the definition of each closure in the https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/